# Unexpected initCause behaviour I cannot overcome

Tags: java

I have a source like this:

```
    Exception e = new Exception("Exception");
    IOException ioE = new IOException("An exception cause");
    e.initCause(ioE);
```

I'm trying to set the cause of the exception "e" and what I get is the exception being set to itself!

I just don't get it. Does my code make any sense or am I going nuts?

Comment: Are you sure about what you're seeing? The code shown works correctly for me and sets the cause of Exception `e` to be the IOException `ioe`.

Comment: I'm trying it again, maybe I'm just getting thrown off by the GWT development mode (I'm using this tool).

Comment: seems the GWT serializer does not encode "cause". I was not crazy and was being played by GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work:

```
package com.daniel.test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Exception e = new Exception("Exception");
    IOException ioE = new IOException("An exception cause");
    e.initCause(ioE);
    throw e;
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Exception
at com.daniel.test.Test.main(Test.java:8)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An exception cause
at com.daniel.test.Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

You can see that the cause is set properly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're conceptually misunderstanding how initCause works. See the Java API, it says that

> It is generally called from within the constructor, or immediately
>   after creating the throwable. If this throwable was created with
>   Throwable(Throwable) or Throwable(String,Throwable), this method
>   cannot be called even once.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause(java.lang.Throwable)